# Mermaid diagram with scrollbars in Azure DevOps wiki

Tags: azure-devops, markdown, mermaid

I am creating a big sequence diagram in Azure Devops wiki, as soon as the number of nodes and interactions increase in Mermaid diagram, it is becoming difficult to view. is there a possibility to fix the diagram size with scroll bars?

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: I have posted a feature request in VS users voice site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I follow this temporarily way until MS upgrades the Mermaid:

1. create a diagram using [Mermaid live editor](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor) and use the required features (such as custom font size, padding, etc)

```py
sequenceDiagram
    %%{init: {'theme': 'default', 'sequence':{'actorMargin': 15, 'height': 130, 'diagramMarginX': 50, 'diagramMarginY': 10, 'messageFontWeight': 'bold', 'actorFontSize': 26, 'actorFontWeight': 800, 'noteFontSize': 26, 'noteFontWeight': 800, 'messageFontSize': 26, 'messageFontWeight': 800}}}%%
    participant A01 
    participant A02
    participant A03
    participant A04
    participant A05
    participant A06
    participant A07
    participant A08
    participant A09
    participant A10

    A01 ->> A02: aa
    A02 ->> A03: bb
    A03 ->> A04: bb
    A04 ->> A05: bb
    A05 ->> A06: bb
    A06 ->> A07: bb
    A07 ->> A08: bb
    A08 ->> A09: bb
    A09 ->> A10: bb
```

2. put this diagram to wiki page
3. create image using [Mermaid live editor](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid-live-editor) (see 'Link to Image' button) and put it to wiki page too

[image]

---

As a result get the next wiki page:

```py
# Sequence diagram

## Image

![](https://mermaid.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)

## Origin diagram

:::mermaid
sequenceDiagram
    %%{init: {'theme': 'default', 'sequence':{'actorMargin': 15, 'height': 130, 'diagramMarginX': 50, 'diagramMarginY': 10, 'messageFontWeight': 'bold', 'actorFontSize': 26, 'actorFontWeight': 800, 'noteFontSize': 26, 'noteFontWeight': 800, 'messageFontSize': 26, 'messageFontWeight': 800}}}%%
    participant A01 
    participant A02
    participant A03
    participant A04
    participant A05
    participant A06
    participant A07
    participant A08
    participant A09
    participant A10

    A01 ->> A02: aa
    A02 ->> A03: bb
    A03 ->> A04: bb
    A04 ->> A05: bb
    A05 ->> A06: bb
    A06 ->> A07: bb
    A07 ->> A08: bb
    A08 ->> A09: bb
    A09 ->> A10: bb
:::
```

Answer (score 2):

You can allow the diagram to render at full width in an Azure DevOps wiki by setting `useMaxWidth` to `false`:

```
::: mermaid
sequenceDiagram
    %%{init: {'sequence':{'useMaxWidth': false}}}%%
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work for `graph` types unfortunately :(

Comment: Silly me, with a slight tweak this worked `%%{init: {'flowchart':{'useMaxWidth': false}}}%%`

Answer (score 1):

I can understand the inconvenience this brings to you. As the content increases, the size of the content becomes smaller, which is not convenient for viewing. But as far as I know it is currently impossible to fix the diagram size with scroll bars.

In addition , [styling](https://mermaid-js.github.io/mermaid/#/sequenceDiagram?id=styling) of a sequence diagram is done by defining a number of css classes. During rendering these classes are extracted from the file located at src/themes/sequence.scss. This is as designed ,We can’t modify it directly.

You could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) site, which is our main forum for product suggestions. After suggest raised, you can vote and add your comments for this feedback. The product team would provide the updates if they view it. Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps.

[image]

Comment: How can we add styling to Mermaid diagram - can we update src/themes/sequence.scss in the source for our wiki? I noticed that there are other styling issues such as centering of text in notes.